# Copy to output directory doesn't work for anything else than content in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I noticed that when I build using publish, the files I mark as "copy always" for "copy to output directory" and with the "build action" "embedded resources", don't get copied to the output directory when I publish, is there a reason why? It works when it's "build action: content" I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the Microsoft doc [Build action values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2019#build-action-values) to know the difference between **content** and **Embedded Resource**.

A file marked as Content can be retrieved as a stream by calling Application.GetContentStream. For ASP.NET projects, these files are included as part of the site when it's deployed.

The file is passed to the compiler as a resource to be embedded in the assembly. You can call System.Reflection.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream to read the file from the assembly.

The following code is used for copying the files from the resources to another place.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] fileNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
        foreach (String fileName in fileNames)
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(@"D:\test\" + fileName))
            {
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(fileName).CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, is there a way to copy all "embedded resources" to the output folder without having to manually copy them to the folders where they are currently sitting?

Comment: @caesar, based on my further test, I find that I can get the files in the output directly when I set copy always and embedded resources. Also, I provide a code example to copy the files in the resource to other place.

Comment: @caesar, you can put the code in your webform load or button click event.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you mean. Do you have a picture?

Comment: @caesar, I mean that I can use the code to read the resource file in the page_Load event. I update my code for it.